# How to convert a HTML email template to VF email template

Tags: sandbox

```
Case.Email_Sender_Name__c}

Thank you for your request.

Your request has been received and will be attended to within : {!Case.SLA_Units__c} Business {!Case.SLA_Time_Measure__c} .

Important: Please respond to this e-mail for any future correspondence regarding the below case number.

Your case number: #{!Case.CaseNumber}

{!User.Name} {!User.Surname}

Electronic Banking Service Helpdesk

Local:                    0860 227 232

International:        +27(11) 335 4007
```

Comment: What is the usecase for converting it to VF template?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to develop it by yourself :)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_creating.htm